# Is there a *shortcode* to make the ball (player) jump if i press a keyboard button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to find the shortest code I can use to jump ( without using Rigidbody )

I am a beginner and I used the Unity engine,
I try to learn basics using the shortest codes,
I want to learn how to make the ball jumping when i press UpArrow or any key i select .

```
float Speed = 4;  
float ground;

void Start()
{
    ground = transform.position.y;
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        transform.Translate(Time.deltaTime * Speed, 0, 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        transform.Translate(Time.deltaTime * -Speed, 0, 0);
    }

    if (ground == transform.position.y && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        // stucked here XD
    }


}
```

Comment: The "shortest code" will not teach you anything. Unity provides a set of controllers with functionality like this for you to learn

Comment: you are right </3
but I'm just looking for the easiest way to learn it
because i cant remember the long codes :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shorter the code does not mean the better the code. Learn to properly write code and the rest will come with ease. If you can write C# fine, then you need to goto the Unity3D Scripting Reference and study some of the API / Framework.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/

However, in this case - Your player needs either a "CharacterController" component, or a "RigidBody" attached to it.

Translation is a simple function used to move Transforms, this should not be used to "Jump" as collision is not used properly.

If you use a RigidBody, you can apply upward force to the object.

All of this code is done for you and can be studied if you import the "Standard Assets" package that comes with Unity (Or from the assets store). You will find Movement Scripts, Camera Scripts, and so on.

Best of luck!